# mysqlimport and avoiding table lock

Tags: mysql-5.7, locking, import, csv

I reviewed the question & answer here ([mysqlimport locks all tables system wide](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/229457/mysqlimport-locks-all-tables-system-wide)) but I seem to still be stuck on this.

I am standing up a new master/slave pair of 5.7 servers, and have already imported the majority of data I need to perform a changeover from these older servers. After the apps are re-pointed to the new database, there will still be lingering day-of data that I will need to move over but I want to do this without locking any tables since this table is updated rather frequently. My primary goal is to make the re-point and the import of this remaining data as invisible as possible.

I have done several tests using `mysqlimport` to bring in the data from a `.csv`, but it doesn't seem that the `--lock-tables=FALSE` or `--lock-tables=0` options are working for me. It's possible I am using the option wrong, too.

Here is what I've done thus far:

1. `mysqlimport -u root -p dbname --fields-terminated-by=',' --fields-enclosed-by='\"' --lines-terminated-by='\n' /path/to/filename.csv` This was to see what occurred without any sort of `--lock-tables` option as I did a test `INSERT` into the table, which was stopped by the `mysqlimport`.
2. Same command string as above, but with `--lock-tables=0` option. Same results as #1.
3. Same command string as above, but with `--lock-tables=FALSE` option. Was able to perform a `INSERT` into the table, but running a `SELECT` to see data caused the `mysqlimport` to fail and report a `Lock wait timeout exceeded` error.

I feel like with #3 I am getting closer to what I am looking to accomplish, but it still seems like I'm either missing something or misunderstanding what can be done to bring this data in. If I have to incur some downtime to bring the data in, then that's what I have to do, but I'd much rather not.

Comment: Did you resolve it?

Comment: No I wasn't able to unfortunately. I ended up migrating the application over to the new database, and exported the data out from that day to a CSV for the app team's auditing and daily reporting.